# Javascript object passing of itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

Looking for some really quick help,

```
contactForm={
    that: this,
    lilfield: 'I just equal this',
    fields: new Array("hc_name","hc_email","hc_telephone"),
    submit_button: jQuery("#hc_submit"),
    init: function(){
        that.lilAlert();
    },
    lilAlert: function(){
        alert("lets pump this out");
    }
}
```

The above is just an example, but effectively what i'm trying to achieve is that the variable that can be used to proceed calls rather than referencing the object 'contactForm' itself. Also that is a little safer to use than this, due to auto passing of this on events such as click etc with jQuery.

Comment: Are you looking for http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.

1. Your `that` is pointing to the `this` that *created* the contactForm, *not* the actual contactForm as you expect.
2. Your `that` is a property of the contact form so you need to access it via `this.that` or `contactForm.that`, which kind of breaks the original purpose.

Either:

1. Reference contactForm itself
2. or define the `that`s inside the functions that need it

   ```
   init: function(){
       var that = this;
       that.lilalert();
   }
   ```

---

If all you want to do is avoid `this` shenanigans, an alternative is using closures (and therefore lexical, static scope instead of dynamic binding via `this`)

```
function make_contact_form(){
    var lilfield: 'I just equal this';
    var fields =  ["hc_name","hc_email","hc_telephone"]; //dont use new Array. its evil
    var submit_button = jQuery("#hc_submit");
    var init = function(){
        lilAlert(); //lilAlert is a name is scope. call it directly
    };
    var lilAlert =  function(){
        alert("lets pump this out");
    };

    return {
        lilfield: lilfield,
        fields: fields,
        submit_button: submit_button,
        init: init,
        lilAlert: lilAlert
    };
}
```

Comment: Hmmm so in reality what i'm trying to do isn't possible? And theres no clever work arounds?

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating it; just call `this.lilAlert()` and it'll work fine, as long as you're calling `init()` **on** the `contactForm`.

```
contactForm.init(); // this will work;
```

.

```
setTimeout(contactForm.init, 1000); // this won't work, as `init()` will have `this` set to `window`
setTimeout(function () { // This approach will work though.
    contactForm.init();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: It does work fine in that sense. But say for instance I make this,

    clickAction: function(){
         this.lilAlert();
    }

And call that from a jQuery bind such as:

    jQuery("#element").bind('click',contactForm.clickAction);

We will now run into problems, as this will become the element clicked on not the object, when referred from the object scope.

Comment: @David; all you need to do is wrap it in an anonymous function like I did to did the `setTimeout` example; `jQuery("#element").bind('click',function() { contactForm.clickAction });`